# multithreading in a gui

Tags: python, multithreading

So this function here is the problem:

```
def scrape(self):
    url = "scrapy crawl myspider -a start_url="

    if not self.onionVar.get() and not self.cnnVar.get() and not self.bbcVar.get(): #if no sites have been selected throw an error
         return tkMessageBox.showerror("Error", "Err[1]: No sites selected. \n --Unable to scrape.")

    if self.onionVar.get():
        url = url + "http://feeds.theonion.com/theonion/daily,http://feeds.theonion.com/theonion/sports,"
    if self.cnnVar.get():
        url = url + "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_world.rss,http://rss.cnn.com/rss/money_latest.rss,http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_allpolitics.rss," \
                "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_us.rss,http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_crime.rss,http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_tech.rss,http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_health.rss," \
                "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_showbiz.rss,http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_travel.rss,http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_living.rss,"

    if self.bbcVar.get():
        url = url + "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml#,"

    cmdline.execute(url.split())
```

I am using Tkinter to make my first GUI program and when I call this function the last line `cmdline.execute(url.split())` will run and then close the program when finished. What I need to do I think is create a new thread and run the function in that. Here is what I tried to do: `self.b = Button(master, text="Scrape", command=thread.start_new_thread(self.scrape, ()))`, but the problem is that Tkinter binds all the return values to the command parameters so it automatically runs the scrape function on startup. If anyone has any ideas it would be very much appreciated.

Sorry if it makes no sense I am terrible at explaining things. Thanks for your time -Sam

Answer (score 1):

### Going distributed

Upon a serious need to distribute the processing, setup a process-to-process messaging, best with some smart, high-level, broker-less, messaging framework & enjoy the full powers of distributed event processing.

**`Tkinter`** will allow your code to both handle local-context processing ( own UI-events ) + also remote events, using the same `Tk().mainloop()` control-loop scheduler.

### Tools to try

May think to test ZeroMQ or nanomsg ( rather than making just another home brewed try to re-invent low-level I/O-s & inter-thread signalling ) for their great services, cool performance and smart ready-made primitives ( archetypes ) for further LEGO-style assemblies for more complex, highly scaleable, fault-resilient, load-balancing and other designs.

### Example of multi-threaded & multi-host distributed UI

1. **`Tkinter`** drives python GUI interactions ( parametrisation + live matplotlib graphs )
2. remote host process, ZeroMQ connected, feeds static Market data upon **`python`** requests
3. a distributed pool-of-remote processes, ZeroMQ inter-connected, orchestrate load-balanced Trade Execution Services against Server-side proprietary Trade Execution interface
4. remote C/MQL4, multithreaded processes, ZeroMQ inter-connected, receive from python computation intensive support and visualise part of that inputs as live predictive graphics on a proprietary Trading Terminal UI

Project has implemented multi-host / multi-head realtime GUI and re-distributed blocking activities into load-balanced / fair-queue-ed pool(s)-of-remote-process-es to shave-off milliseconds and microseconds that need not be spent & wasted on non-core job(s) on the main cluster.